# Telegram Bot API выполнять действие при нажатие на ссылку

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Что надо сделать, что бы при нажатие на кнопку InlineKeyboardButton URL выполнялось действие до переходе по ссылке, например добавление записи в БД. Событие похожее на onclick в js, но не могу найти нечего похожего в документации

Comment: это невозможно штатными средствами

Comment: А как можно реализовать это? Или как то инициировать переход по ссылке без нажатия кнопки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принудительное перенаправление пользователя по ссылке (*открытие браузера*) невозможно.

Попробуйте использовать сервис типа [bitly](https://bitly.com/) для отслеживания статистики по кликам. Если же вам нужно записывать какие-то данные о пользователе в БД и ссылка ведёт на ваш веб-сервис, то добавьте необходимые данные в параметры ссылки и делайте сохранение в БД на стороне веб-сервиса.

Answer (score -1):

К примеру регестрируем кнопку

```
keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
key_help = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="\u2139 Что я умею?",
                                              callback_data="help")
keyboard.add(key_help)
key_search = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="\ud83d\udd0d Искать программу",
                                                callback_data="search")
keyboard.add(key_search)
```

Далее пишем функцию коллбек

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "search":
            search(call.message)
        elif call.data == "help":
            send_help(call.message)
```

Comment: В кнопках когда они именно c URL нельзя настроить callback_data. InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти", url = "https://yandex.ru/", callback_data="1") пробовал писать вот так выдаёт ошибку

Comment: А подробнее что за ошибка? Может callback_data не нужно указывать?

Comment: TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback_data'